# The output of sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors appears to be sorted by neighbor rank - why does the documentation not commit to that?

Tags: scikit-learn

When you look at the result of a sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors query, the distances will always be in ascending order, and the indices are in the order "nearest neighbor", "second nearest neighbor", etc.

But the [sklearn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.html) never states the above.

My question would be: is that a deliberate omission, or is it just so standard that the result would be ordered that it does not require mentioning it?

Consider this example code, adapted from [53886289](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53886289/confused-with-the-output-of-sklearn-neighbors-nearestneighbors):

```
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])
nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=2, algorithm='ball_tree').fit(X)
X_query = np.array([[0, 1]])
distances, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(X_query)
```

Output:

```
distances -> array([[1., 2.]])

indices -> array([[3, 4]])
```